# align-items center does not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to vertically center the h1 with the a's in the span but somehow the navigation buttons are a couple pixels higher than the h1. I have tried solving this but i couldn't find a way. So i'm hoping you maybe know what the problem could be.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav nav {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <nav>
    <div>
      <h1><a href="index.html">workout</a></h1>
    </div>
    <span>
      <a id='home' href="index.html">index</a>
      <a id='work' href="pricing.html">pricing</a>
      <a id='contact' href="schedule.html">schedule</a>
    </span>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: _How_ do you mean they are higher?

Comment: If you add a border to all the `a`, you'll see they are all centered: https://jsfiddle.net/3b4p56b5/

Comment: Do note that the character in a font have an internal offset, and that you can't base the centering on, as it is unknown to any CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.nav` div styling for this. check updated snippet below..

```css
h1{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:2em;
  font-weight:normal;

}
h1 a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  font-size: 1em;
}
/*.nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}*/
.nav nav{
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <nav>
 <div>
   <h1><a href="index.html">workout</a></h1>
 </div>
 <span>
   <a id='home' href="index.html">index</a>
   <a id='work' href="pricing.html">pricing</a>
   <a id='contact' href="schedule.html">schedule</a>
 </span>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: How would i horizontally center it then?

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald and Super User, I measured with this fix and no change what so ever.